# Modular Arithmetic with large exponents

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I have to return $a^x b^y(mod p)$

However I'm having difficulty doing this with such large numbers.

I know I can change the format to $a  b (mod p)^n$ and I will get a number however I'm just not sure how to work with different exponents, and numbers so large, and still get the correct answer.

$a = 1531201089928563$
$b = 5232015514746838$
$p = 36591670045183523$

$x = 31146826187279844$
$y = 1747419798738$

It is in computer programming.  I'm just unsure of how to structure the formula correctly and would like some guidance.

Comment: Unless it is an exercise in computer programming you should not be doing this.

Comment: It is in computer programming, I'm just unsure of how to structure the formula correctly.

Comment: Do you have the tools to find $ab \bmod p$? $a^2 \bmod p$?

Comment: Do you have data types large enough to store $p^2$ without overflowing?

Answer (score 0):

First reduction: ensure  $x,y$  are replaced by something less than $p$. This is by Fermat's theorem which states that $a^x=a^r\pmod p$ where $r$ is the remainder from $x$ when divided by $p-1$.

Next use the iterated squaring method: I'll sketch this.  Normally to calculate $a^{41}$ one needs 40 multiplications. Iterated squaring exploits  the binary representation, $41=32+8+1$.  So $a^{41}= a^{32}\times a^8 \times a^1$.
This requires 2 multiplications, to calculates $a^{32}$ repeatedly square $a$, and on the way you would also have computed $a^8$. (All this holds for mudular exponentiation. At every stage you can calculates the result mod p.

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are actually already less than $p$. Calculation of $a^{41}$ requires $7$ multiplications, since squaring counts as a multiplication.

Comment: @Joffan. Thanks for pointing out the missing info.

Comment: Also I'd say the *very first* thing to do is check whether $p$ is prime. :-) (It is)